# Update element stl list of lists

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

I am working with a list of a list of vector of ints (`std::list<std::list<std::vector<int>>> z(nlevel)`).

I might have something like:

```
{ {1} {2} {3} }
{ {1 2} {2 1} {1 3} }
{ {1 2 3} {2 1 3} {1 2 4} }
```

I need to remove the non-unique combination of integers, so e.g., the second element of the list above should become

```
{ { 1 2 } {1 3} }
```

This is a large object, so I'm trying to update each element of the outermost list by reference. I've tried something like:

```
lit = z.begin();
for (i = 0; i < nlevel; i++) {
    distinct_z(*lit, primes);
    lit++;
}
```

where `distinct_z` is a function to find the unique vector combinations by reference, but this doesn't seem to affect the list `z`. Note: `distinct_z` does work fine in another part of my code where I am already working with the ith element of the list. I've provided `distinct_z` below. It includes some unique data types from the Rcpp package in R, but is hopefully understandable. Essentially, I use the log sum of prime numbers to identify non-unique combinations of integers because the order of the integers does not matter. To reiterate, `distinct_z` does work in another part of my code where I pass it an actual list of vectors of ints. The problem seems to be that I'm trying to pass something using an iterator.

```
void distinct_lz(std::list<std::vector<int>> &lz,
                      const IntegerVector &primes) {
  int i, j, npids = lz.size();

  NumericVector pids(npids);
  std::list<std::vector<int>>::iterator lit = lz.begin();
  int z_size = lit -> size();
  for(i = 0; i < npids; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < z_size; j++) {
      // cprime = primes[lit -> at(j)];
      // pids[i] += log(cprime);
      // cprime = primes[lit -> at(j)];
      pids[i] += log(primes[lit -> at(j)]);
    }
    lit++;
  }
  LogicalVector dup = duplicated(round(pids, 8));
  lit = lz.begin();
  for(i = 0; i < npids; i++) {
    if(dup(i) == 1) {
      lz.erase(lit);
    }
    lit++;
  }
}
```

What is the best approach for doing what I want?

Background: The data structure probably seems unnecessarily complicated, but I'm enumerating all connected subgraphs starting at a vertex using a breadth-first approach. So given a current subgraph, I see what other vertices are connected to create a set of new subgraphs and repeat. I initially did this using a list of vectors of ints, but removing repeats was ridiculously slow due to the fact that I had to copy the current object if I removed part of the vector. This approach is much faster even though the structure is more complicated.

Edit: Here is a solution that mostly does what I want, though it results in some undesired copying. I updated `distinct_z` to return a copy of the object instead of modifying the reference, and then replaced the element at `lit`.

```
  lit = z.begin();
  for (i = 0; i < nlevel; i++) {
    (*lit) = distinct_z(*lit, primes);
    lit++;
  }
```

Comment: Showing `distinct_z` should probably help...

Comment: removing non-unique elements is easiest done by using a container that does not allow duplicate elements, eg a `std::set`. Better show your attempt, otherwise this is in danger of getting closed as a duplicate of a "how to remove duplicates" question, which might be a good direction but of course cannot address the problems in your code. Also read about [mcve]

Comment: @Jarod42 @formelyknownas I added ```distinct_z```. Thanks for your help! ```distinct_z``` functions properly in other parts of my code, but not in this particular context when trying to use an iterator.

Comment: seems like the interesting part is in `duplicated` for which you didnt show the code.Please read about [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there is a well known idiom known as the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) for removing elements from an STL container. It basically involves shuffling unwanted items to the end of the container and then erasing the unwanted tail.

We can use a predicate function (e.g. lambda) to select the items we want to erase and use functions from `<algorithm>`. In your case we use a set of set of ints (`std::<set<int>>`) to store unique combinations. Convert each vector in the list to a set of ints and delete it if hasn't been seen before.

```
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void distinct_lz(std::list<std::vector<int>>& lz)
{
    std::set<std::set<int>> unqiueNums;

    lz.erase(std::remove_if(lz.begin(), lz.end(),
        [&unqiueNums](std::vector<int>& v) {
            std::set<int> s{ v.cbegin(), v.cend() };
            if (unqiueNums.find(s) != unqiueNums.end())
                return true;
            else
            {
                unqiueNums.insert(s);
                return false;
            }
        }), lz.end());

}

int main()
{
    std::list<std::vector<int>> lv = { {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {3,4} };
    distinct_lz(lv);
    for (auto &v: lv)
    {
        for( auto n: v)
        {
            std::cout << n << " ";
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

1 2
1 3 
3 4

Working version [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nREu8m).

Comment: Thanks for your help. You really went above and beyond.

Comment: @dr_jfrench No problem.